# Failure to install ServletExec 4.2

Tags: troubleshooting

We are attempting to install ServletExec and get this puzzling error during the installation:

[image]

- we can install to XPSP2 with out getting the error.
- we get the error when attempting to install on server 2003 hosts.
- however we have an existing installation of ServletExec on another 2003sp2 host

We are using install shield runtime version 0701; ServletExec is several years old, perhaps we should revert back to an earlier version of install shield?

We have tried running the installer as an Administrator to no avail.

Thanks SF community, we appeal to you for suggestions - you're our only hope!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out if you put add the commandline argument `-wait`, all's well.

There you go.